# argc atoi argv, Opencv, C++

Tags: c++, opencv

can you explain what does it mean?

```
 argc >= 3 ? atoi(argv[2]) : 40;
```

And second question : does exist libarries of function - parameters which is necessary, structure something like this

```
 CVAPI(void)  cvAddS( const CvArr* src, CvScalar value, CvArr* dst,
                 const CvArr* mask CV_DEFAULT(NULL));
```

Comment: I don't at all understand the second part of your question.

Comment: Learn the C++ basic: *ternary operator* and then look for what `atoi` does. In C++, `std::atoi` should be avoided, and `std::stoi` should be used instead (which is added to C++11).

Answer (score 1):

```
argc >= 3 ? atoi(argv[2]) : 40;
```

means "if argc is greater or equal to three return `argv[2]` converted to integer, else return `40`. "return" in the previous statement is a bit misleading. In reality the expression resolves to one thing or the other, depending on a condition.

```
condition ? true_expr : false_expr
```

By convention, `argc` has the number of parameters passed to main, and `argv` is an array containing those parameters. `argv[0]` is the name of the executable itself, so `argv[1]` woudl be the first command line parameter after the executable name.

Answer (score 1):

The first snippet uses the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#C) to check is there is at least two arguments (the first one is the program name, therefore the `3` in the condition) and if it is then the expression returns the value of the second argument as an integer ([`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) converts a string to an integer), else the expression returns the value `40`.